# Cross-Browser 3D Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to develop a small browser-based game. I've been fiddling around quite a bit with getting an animation to work the way I want it to.

The problem is that it works alright in Opera, quite well in Edge (although it crops the circle a bit). However, as always, IE fails quite a bit.

The example doesn't show the function perfectly, even though it normally works in my browser (Opera).

The card should flip from its absolute position, expand to `90%` height AND move to complete center of the screen. There will be more cards with absolute positions and therefore it would be ideal to only have one "move" animation to center.

Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".card", function() {
    $(this).addClass("flipover");
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });
  //if (window.document.documentMode) { alert("Use another browser!"); } 
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  perspective: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.cardfront,
.cardback {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.cardfront {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  background: red;
}

.cardback {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: blue;
}

.hover:hover {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 45deg);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.flipover {
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  margin-left: -45vh;
  margin-top: -45vh;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.pos1r {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5vh;
  left: 50vh;
}

.pos2r {
  top: 35vh;
  left: 35vh;
}

.pos3r {
  top: 55vh;
  left: 35vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card pos1r hover">
  <div class="cardfront">
  </div>
  <div class="cardback">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dumo6r04/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is more or less what you were attempting to do - I applied the `transform-origin` and used `translate3D` to help move the `card` centrally.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(document).on("click", ".card", function() {
  $(this).addClass("flipover");
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
 });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    perspective: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.card
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
    border-radius: 50%;

    perspective: 1000px;

    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin:center;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.cardfront,
.cardback {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
    transform-origin:center;
}

.cardfront {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background: red;
}

.cardback {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: blue;
}


.hover:hover {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 45deg);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.flipover {
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 90vh;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3D(-35%,-45%,0);

    margin-left: -45vh;
    margin-top: -45vh;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}


.pos1r {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -5vh;
    left: 50vh;
}


.pos2r {
    top: 35vh;
    left: 35vh;
}

.pos3r {
    top: 55vh;
    left: 35vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card pos1r hover">
 <div class="cardfront"></div>
 <div class="cardback"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is basically the function yes - however it still doesn't work in Explorer. And also it doesn't really work in Edge since it transforms to one location and then jumps to center :)

Comment: However - i tried working a bit more with it now. It seems like keeping the .pos* class messes it up a bit - maybe it's better to adjust the values in that div instead of assigning a class with a new position? :)